# Foreach over object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach, angular7

I've got a little problem with my code. I already have a piece of code looping on an array (like this:[image: pic1])
I take this array and turn it like this:[image: pic2]

Here is the piece of code :

```
processPostData(data: any) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(data.resources, (element: any) => {
        console.log(element);
        Object.keys(element).forEach((key) => {
            console.log(key);
            if ((element[key] == null || element[key] == '') && ['process_limit_date', 'creation_date', 'closing_date', 'countAttachments', 'countNotes'].indexOf(key) === -1) {
                element[key] = this.lang.undefined;
            } else if (["senders","recipients"].indexOf(key) > 0) {
                if (element[key].length > 1) {
                    console.log(element[key]);
                    element[key] = this.lang.isMulticontact;
                } else {
                    element[key] = element[key][0];
                }
            } else if (key == 'status_icon' && element[key] == null) {
                element[key] = 'fa-question undefined';
            }

        });
    });

    return data;
}
```

Now the problem is that I modify my input "data" and now I have an object, like this : 
[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytjHe.png)

I have now an Object instead of an Array and I didn't manage to loop through it the same way before. How could I do that? At least, for the first loop, and get an Array, or an Object, with the content of the "23" and "24" indexes of the Object.

Tell me if I'm not clear enough, pretty hard to me to be as precise as possible

Comment: Images won't be helpful, you need to add your data and try to create demo.

Comment: Where can I do the demo ?

Comment: edit your question and try to create snippet.

Comment: Why can't you parse your data programmatically (transform your objects manually) and then iterate? What is exactly the problem, that you don't know what format you are going to receive or that you don't know how to combine "23" and "24"?

Answer (score 3):

i am not sure if i understood you correctly, but you can iterate over objects like this:

```
for(let key in object) {
let child = object[key];
// Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, object fields are not iterable in array-fashion way. You can however to try to wrap your handler in folliwing to be able to parse both array and object form:

```
if(Array.isArray(input)) {
  /* Do what you are already doing */
} else { /* We are working with object */
  Object.keys(input).forEach((key) => {
    /* Here you can iterate over each key in object */
  })
}
```

But still, your question scope is rather unclear

Answer (score 0):

Before you iterated through `data.resources`
With your changes, you have to iterate through `data.resources.docs`
Try something like that:

```
data.resources.forEach(resource => {
    console.log(resource);
    resource.docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc);
        // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, I've noticed that you treat `resource.senders` and `resource.recipients` as array whereas it's a string in your screenshot.
I also noticed that if you have more than one sender/recipient you will assign `this.lang.isMulticontact` to resource.senders/recipient, so you won't have your senders/recipients anymore, is that what you want ?

Note that you should not modify your data parameter it can lead to **undesirable side-effects.**

```
processPostData(data) {
  const dataToProcess = [...data];
  dataToProcess.resources.forEach((resource) => {
    const propertiesUndefined = ['process_limit_date', 'creation_date', 'closing_date', 'countAttachments', 'countNotes'];
    propertiesUndefined.forEach((property) => {
      if (!resource[property]) { 
        resource[property] = this.lang.undefined;
      }
    });
    const propertiesMultiContact = ['senders', 'recipients'];
    propertiesMultiContact.forEach((property) => {
      if (resource[property] instance of Array && resource[property].length > 1) {
        resource[property] = this.lang.isMulticontact;
      }
    });
   if (!resource['status_icon']) {
     resource['status_icon'] = 'fa-question undefined';
   }
  });
  return dataToProcess;
}
```